# channel live streaming from website in android

Tags: android, video-streaming

I want to play live streaming from a channel hosted by Bambuser website through my Android app.
I tried using both webview and videoview and giving them my channel link but the video is not being played I think It's probably cause It's swf by bambuser.
Any idea how to get this stream playing in my app or any examples? Thanks a lot

Comment: I know i should convert swf into mp4 but can i convert an swf live streaming url? and can i do all that inside my app??